# How to bind dropdownlist in grid view using webservices?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services, gridview, drop-down-menu

I have 4 dropdown list in my grid view. I want them to be loaded using webservices. Is it possible to do so? How to accomplish this?

Comment: Sure it's possible.  Add references to the web services, connect to them, retrieve the data and bind it to the dropdown lists.

Answer (score 1):

Yes You can populate using Webservices. You can try like this. I havent tried this.

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Connection"].ToString());
[WebMethod]
public DataSet DDLList()
{
conn.Open();    
SqlCommand ad1 = new SqlCommand("select Id,ValueText from Table", conn);
SqlDataAdapter adapt = new SqlDataAdapter(ad1);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapt.Fill(ds);
conn.Close();
return ds;
}
```

In the aspx.cs Page, You can call this webmethod and return DataSet.

```
Public DataSet FillDDl()
{
UrService.Service test = new UrService.Service();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = test.DDLList();
return ds;
}
```

In the aspx markup, You can call the `FillDDl` method.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" DataSource='<%# FillDDl() %>' DataTextField="ValueText" DataValueField="Id" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```